# using the checkbox value from a jquery DataTable in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I have a jQuery DataTable in a Laravel App. I want to confirm the previously stored data from someone else by using a checkbox. When that checkbox is checked I want to update that record's attribute `is_confirmed` with the value 1 (true). Now I can get all the records that i need to confirm from the database. However when I try to confirm one of them, every single record is confirmed even why i leave the  other checkbox unchecked.

I guess that the error is in the controller update method below:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $is_validated = $request->get('is_validated');

    foreach ($is_validated as $valid_Id) {
        if($valid_Id.value(1)) //<-here i suspect that the error is
    {
            DB::table('reports')->update(['is_validated' => 1, 'validated_by' => $user->id]);
        }
    }
    return view('validate.update');
}
```

I tried changing the value of the checkbox with the code below.

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
    cb = $(this);
    cb.val(cb.prop('checked'));
    cb.value = 1;
});
```

And I also tried using radio buttons, however since they all have the same name i could only select 1 button in all the records.

I'm stuck at this point and it seems that I can't figure it out on my own. All the help or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you update a table, it's going to update all the columns unless you chain a `where()` onto the end to select only the record you need to update.  You need to also have some sort of identifier for each row that can get updated so that you can update only the row you wish to update each time.

If there are lots of rows, it would also be a good idea to optimize the query.  Currently it's going to run once for each row it updates.  Ideally, you'd want to come up with something like the following...

```
// Reset is_validate fields to 0
DB::table('reports')->update(['is_validated' => 0);

// Reapply is_validate to each valid field.
DB::table('reports')->update(['is_validated' => 1, 'validated_by' => $user->id])->whereIn('row_id', $request->get('row_ids'));
```

This way, you have 2 queries instead of lots.